# Mouse keeps disappearing, how to fix this?

Tags: microsoft-flight-simulator

I don't know why it's happening but when it does I lose control of the plane.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you playing in windowed mode possibly?

Comment: @TimmyJim it happens with fullscreen and windowed for me